# App Working In Real Device But Crashing In Android Studio Emulator

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, android-fragments

Please Help Me

I Have Made An App Which Is Running Without Crashes In Real Device But Stopping In Android Studio Emulator

MainActivity.java

```
package com.eco.hrmecoservices;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            // Don't Do Anything
        }
        else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},100);
        }
        BottomNavigationView bottomnav=findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomnav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListner);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new home_fragment()).commit();
        db.collection("User Details").whereEqualTo("email", user.getEmail()).limit(1)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        boolean taskbool = task.getResult().isEmpty();
                        if(taskbool){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, phone_number_verify.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else{
                            String phoneNumber = "";
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()) {
                                 phoneNumber = doc.get("PhoneNumber").toString();
                            }
                            SharedPreferences mode = getSharedPreferences("UserPhoneNumber", MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mode.edit();
                            editor.putString("PhoneNumber", phoneNumber);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchViewItem = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchViewItem);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListner =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull @NotNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.home:
                    selectedFragment = new home_fragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.cart:
                    selectedFragment = new cart_fragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.orders:
                    selectedFragment = new order_fragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.settings:
                    selectedFragment = new settings_fragment();
                    break;
            }
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    selectedFragment).commit();
            return true;
        }
    };
    public void OrderSanitization(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OrderSanitization.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    public void logout(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Logout From HRM Eco Services?");
        alert.setMessage("Caution! Logging Out From HRM Eco Services");

        alert.setPositiveButton("Yes, Logout", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Logged Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent login = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(login);
            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    }
                });

        alert.show();
    }

    public void start_shopping(View view) {
        BottomNavigationView bottomnav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomnav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new home_fragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

home_fragment.java

```
package com.eco.hrmecoservices;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;


public class home_fragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }
}
```

This Activity Stops IDK Why

Emulator Which I Have Used Tested: Pixel-2(Nougat), Pixel-4(Nougat), NexusOne(Nougat), Pixel-2(Q)

Plz Help

Thanks, And Regards

Krishna

Comment: Please, Help :-)

Comment: Hi @krishna, can you please share the error you are getting while running your application on an emulator?

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure the emulator is connected to the internet
- Listen for events and Log the errors:

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      //code here
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
      Log.w(TAG, "oops an error", databaseError.toException());
   }
};
mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

Comment: It is connected to the internet :-) and google Oauth is working fine but IDK Why my app is crashing in the emulator and working fine in real android device